# Как достать номер версии и билда приложения с Jenkins?

Tags: c#, jenkins

У меня есть приложение на c#, которое билдится на Jenkins. Номера билдов идут по порядку от 1 до 23 на данный момент.

На About окне мне нужно выводить номер версии приложения вмести с номером билда. Вручную править каждый раз AssemblyVersion не вариант.)

Делала попытку установить `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.*")]`, но номер билда получился 25137, хотя на самом Дженкенсе с нумерацией все нормально

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста как доставать номер текущего билда из Дженкинса?

Comment: Про Jenkins я не в курсе (гуглится [это](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Change+Assembly+Version)), как достать потом эту инфу - [пример](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/master/src/Arma3BE.Client.Modules.MainModule/About.xaml.cs#L30) моего окна About

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо, да я видела информацию об этом плагине, но к сожелению я не имею прав админа чтоб настроить его. А Вы используете его?

Comment: Не, я не использую Jenkins совсем

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть несколько способов, вот некоторые из них, на мой взгляд, вполне удобные:

### Jenkins Environment Variables

Если вам надо получить номер прямо в pipeline и использовать в своём скрипте, например groovy, то номер билда будет доступен в переменной `env.BUILD_NUMBER`
Полный список подобных переменных можно найти здесь:

```
http://YourJenkinsSite:8080/env-vars.html/
```

Некоторые переменные, например `currentBuild.displayName` могут быть изменены

Подробнее здесь:

```
http://YourJenkinsSite:8080/pipeline-syntax/globals#currentBuild
```

### Jenkins REST API

Этот вариан, возможно, вам больше подойдёт:
доступно для каждой джобы, например:

```
http://YourJenkinsSite:8080/job/YourJobName/api/
```

доступны как XML, так и JSON форматы:

**XML**:

```
http://YourJenkinsSite:8080/job/YourJobName/api/xml
```

вывод вида:

```
<build _class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun">
<number>2200</number>
<url>http://localhost:8080/job/test_pipeline_copy/2200/</url></build>
```

**JSON**:

```
http://YourJenkinsSite:8080/job/YourJobName/api/json?pretty=true
```

вывод вида:

```
"builds" : [
    {
      "_class" : "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun",
      "number" : 2200,
      "url" : "http://YourJenkinsSite:8080/job/YourJobName/2200/"
    }]
```

Дальше задача лишь спарсить нужные вам значения

если вам нужен только последний билд, можно использовать

```
http://YourJenkinsSite:8080/job/YourJobName/lastBuild/api/json?pretty=true
```

как вариант, доступ только к номеру последнего билда:

```
http://YourJenkinsSite:8080/job/YourJobName/lastBuild/api/xml?tree=displayName,lastBuild[number]
```

Или последнего успешного билда:

```
http://YourJenkinsSite:8080/job/YourJobName/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json?tree=displayName,lastBuild[number]
```

Замените `YourJenkinsSite:8080` и `YourJobName` на актуальные для вас значения